# the intersection of two spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

though it may be a trivial question but I have some trouble in finding the intersection between two spaces for example
$$ W = \mathrm{Sp}\{(1,3,4),(2,5,1)\} \\ U = \mathrm{Sp}\{(1,1,2),(2,2,1) \}$$
**Find a span** $U \cap W$.

I understand that this have to be true but I am not sure how to get the general solution after I finished simplifying the shape
$\alpha(1,1,2) + \beta(2,2,1) = \gamma(1,3,4) + \delta(2,5,1)$
so I reached
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|rr}
1 & 0 & -3 & -6\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 21
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Looks like you set up a matrix with the coefficients of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ left of the vertical bar, and those for $\gamma$ and $\delta$ to the right of the vertical bar. If that is accurate... then that isn't standard. Have you ever solved a system of linear equations by Gaussian elimination where you have some variables on one side of the equal sign and some variables on the other side?

Comment: yeah that the problem we did solve like this only  one time in class while there where variables on both sides ,i don't remember how to deal with them being on both sides  though  I do know how to solve like standard  I hope to understand both

Comment: Just move all the variables to the same side and solve. If you have $\alpha+2\beta=\gamma+2\delta$, that's the same as $\alpha+2\beta-\gamma-2\delta=0$. You should have three equations in four unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, "$\mathbf{span}\ U\cap W$" is a little [pleonastic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleonasm), as $U\cap W$ is necessarily a subspace, and hence equal to its own span.

What you did, trying to row-reduce a "double augmented" matrix where both sides of the augmentation correspond to variables, is bound to be both confusing and end up looking like nonsense... which is exactly what happened.

You are trying to find the vectors that lie in the intersection. Fair enough. You are attempting to do this by finding all values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$ (**four** variables) such that
$$\alpha(1,3,4) + \beta(2,5,1) = \gamma(1,1,2) + \delta(2,2,1).\tag{1}$$
Again, fair enough. We can push this through, if you keep your head about you.

We can move everything to the left hand side, and write this as
$$\alpha(1,3,4) + \beta(2,5,1) - \gamma(1,1,2) - \delta(2,2,1) = (0,0,0),$$
which translates to
$$(\alpha+2\beta-\gamma-2\delta, 3\alpha+5\beta-\gamma-2\delta, 4\alpha+\beta-2\gamma-\delta) = (0,0,0).$$
This in turn yields a homogeneous system of three equations in four unknowns:
$$\begin{array}{rcccccccl}
\alpha & + & 2\beta & - & \gamma & - & 2\delta & = & 0\\
3\alpha & + & 5\beta & - & \gamma & - & 2\delta &=& 0\\
4\alpha & + & \beta & - & 2\gamma & - & \delta & = & 0.
\end{array}$$
The solutions to this system will give you the vectors that lie in the intersection, by telling you which values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\delta$ yield the same vector on both sides of $(1)$.

Solving this system by Gaussian elimination, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2\\
3 & 5 & -1 & -2\\
4 & 1 & -2 & -1
\end{array}\right) &\to \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2\\
0 & -1 & 2 & 4\\
0 & -7 & 2 & 7
\end{array}\right) \to \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
0 & 0 & -12 & -21
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & -1 & -2\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{7}{4}\end{array}\right)\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & 0 & -\frac{1}{4}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{2}{4}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{7}{4}\end{array}\right)\\
&\to \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{4}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{7}{4}
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
So for each value of $\delta$, if we set
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha &= -\frac{3}{4}\delta,\\
\beta & = \frac{1}{2}\delta,\\
\gamma &= -\frac{7}{4}\delta,
\end{align*}$$
we should get a point of intersection. Indeed, setting $\delta=0$ gives us that $(0,0,0)$ belongs to both spaces. Setting $\delta=4$ gives $\alpha=-3$, $\beta=2$, and $\gamma=-7$, and we can verify that
$$-3(1,3,4) +2(2,5,1) = (1,1,-10)\in W$$
and
$$-7(1,1,2)+4(2,2,1) = (1,1,-10)\in U,$$
so the vector $(1,1,-10)$ lies in both. Etc.

So... how do we describe all the vectors in the intersection? Well, the simplest way is to note that given a value of $\delta$, you must have $\gamma=-\frac{7}{4}\delta$. Thus, all vectors are of the form
$$-\frac{7}{4}\delta(1,1,2) + \delta(2,2,1) = \delta\left( (2,2,1) - \frac{7}{4}(1,1,2)\right).$$
From here you can find a basis and describe the span. Alternatively, for each value of $\delta$, using the corresponding values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the left hand side of $(1)$ we have the vector
$$-\frac{3}{4}\delta(1,3,4) + \frac{1}{2}\delta(2,5,1)$$
from which again it is easy to see that you have all multiples of a particular vector, giving you the span.

Comment: thank you this was needed, what a great explanation!